Help me identify this Twilight Zone-ish scene I remember!
I remember a woman near a well. They are both on a hilltop and there's a house there.
She keeps throwing stuff in the well and getting as a reward coins and jewels and a message in the form of "Our scientists determined that this is chocolate, here is payment for you contribution. Please send more samples."
I remember a last scene where a man falls in the well and she receives a lot of coins and jewels and the same message, but that the scientists determined he was chicken, and he was delicious.
It might be twilight zone or it might be tales of the crypt, but I couldn't find out where this scene is from.

Amazing Stories, Season 2, Episode 9. Episode was called Thanksgiving, (1986).  From the user review:

Calvin (David Carradine) is a nasty guy living in the desert with his
  step-daughter (Kyra Sedgwick). He treats her rather poorly and berates
  her yet she seems blissfully happy despite this. One day, something
  really weird happens with the well Calvin is trying to dig. It turns
  out to be a much deeper hole and there is SOMETHING living down there.
  When he drops a flashlight down there, whoever or whatever is down
  there shows their gratitude by tying a small bundle to his rope. When
  he opens it, he finds it's full of gold!! Now the greedy Calvin is
  going to the store to buy LOTS of flashlights to send down into the
  hole! During his absence, the step-daughter sends down a dictionary
  and some ham. This time they include a note, in English, explaining
  that their scholars have deciphered their language and they are
  thanking them for the ham...and they want more food. They also include
  some very expensive jewelry. Next, she sends down some raw chickens.
  What's next?

Based on the short story "Hey You Down There!", by Harold Rolseth.
